# resilience4j + spring boot 2 + EndpointAutoConfiguration class not found exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resilience4j

Resilience4j version: 1.1.0

Java version: 1.8

Spring boot : 2.2.0

I am trying to configure the Resilience4j with spring boot project but getting below class not found

org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [**org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.EndpointAutoConfiguration**]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:327)

**Java Code as follows** :

```
@RateLimiter(name ="service1",fallbackMethod = "rateLimiterfallback")
    @PostMapping(value = "${URL_AUTH}")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthRespDTO> fetchToken(@RequestParam("userId") String Id, @RequestParam("password") String pwd, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) { 
    }
```

**application.yml as below**

```
resilience4j.ratelimiter:
    instances:
    service1:
      limitForPeriod: 1
      limitRefreshPeriod: 100000
      timeoutDuration: 1000ms
```

I have below dependencies mentioned in POM.xml .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-ratelimiter</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help me in resolving the issue .

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Resilience4j is build against Spring Boot 2.1.4, 2.2.x contains breaking changes and will generally not work. You have to wait for 2.2 support or do the configuration yourself. Also please add your dependencies as code instead of an image.

Comment: I am able to fix the issue , it was required spring-boot-starter-actuator and spring-boot-starter-aop to fix issue .

Answer (score 1):

For fixing this issue you have to update the POM with the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` and `spring-boot-starter-aop` dependencies.

At present you have a dependency of `spring-boot-actuator` which should be updated to `spring-boot-starter-actuator`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Note : Release version of spring boot depends on your project.

[Similar issue reference](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/746)